# What is quantum mechanical explanation of resistance?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, electrical-resistance, conductors

I would be very happy if I get any help with any of this questions. And I am sorry if I make any grammatical mistakes, I don't know grammar well. I guess, the problem for understanding how resistance works is my poor understanding of quantum mechanics.

I heard about thermistors. NTC thermistors are made from semiconductors in a ceramic body. Another question, why there is such ceramic body? Is it mainly for structure durability and heat conducting reasons?(I am not sure about properties of ceramics in electronics) According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor#Construction_and_materials), PTC thermistors are usually prepared from barium (Ba), strontium, or lead titanates (e.g. PbTiO3). So what is the reason for these specific materials?

I can somewhat understand about NTC ones, they use semiconductors. Perhaps, heating results in somewhat less probability of electrons staying in that occupied state due to boltzman distrubution, thus less probability of energy transfer to the conducting atom or molecules via relaxation. Also, less probability of electron being on the occupied state gives more probability of electrons to be on the conducting state. But, how more electrons in the conducting state available, makes resistance(heat dissipation due to electron current) lower? I am not sure. How resistance work?

PTC thermistors case: Conducting metal atoms start to jiggle around, thus creating more "frictions" to passing electrons. How can I understand it in a more quantum physics/chemistry/mechanics way? (just in case: I am 2nd year chemistry student who was trying to learn how to do basic electronic stuff on arduino or not and was learning resistors in more details by this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYcLFHgVCn0). Then, got curios about thermistor composition)

Also, why it is not the case in a other metal or carbon film resistors?

How metal's or any other material's expansion or compression upon heating effects the resistance? Maybe is it due to compression expansion? But barium expands upon heating meanwhile, in strain gauge expansion causes reduced resistance.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Anderson localization?

Comment: @Mass Thanks you man. I had no idea what is that. I read from wikipedia and I still didn't get it.  I feel like I have to start from basics and get "stronger" in it. Too much terminology that I don't get. Few introductory chapters from physical chemistry book seems to be not enough. I am planning to continue/start reading feynman lectures on physics and Statistical Mechanics by Mcquarrie. I would be happy for any advice.

Comment: @ malikbeyy, People used to discuss the electrical conductivity instead of the resistance. Classical conductivity comes from the Drude model, with subtle quantum mechanical reformulation. You can check this lecture notes: https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0402203

Comment: @ Mass Thanks again. I am sorry that I was late to thank you.